# Cascading inserts using ASP.Net with MVC in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a web-page that displays a list of multiple potential therapists for a rehab referral.  The therapists that are selected are saved to a database table.  The problem is, as it loops through the list of selected therapists, it is inserting too many records as follows:

1st in list: 1 record in database

2nd in list: 2 records in database

3rd in list: 3 records in database

and so on.

I am adding each selected therapist to a TherapistService which has a database context behind it.

Once all the therapists have been added, I am executing a Save command.  It was formerly executing a Save command for each Therapist, but this had the same effect.

To make things worse, it works as expected in Visual Studio using the Dev Web Server, but doesn't work in IIS on a test web server.

I would post code, but I am relatively new to MVC and wouldn't know what is needed and not needed for this issue so it would be a LOT of code.  I am hoping that someone can just point me in the right direction.

Here is some code:

This is from the Controller:

```
private ITherapistService _therpService;

for each selected therapist
{
    ReferralTherapist newReferralTherap = new ReferralTherapist();
    //information on referral set
    _therpService.InsertReferralTherapist(newReferralTherap);
}

_therpService.ExecuteSave();
```

This is from the Therapist Service:

```
private TheUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

public bool InsertReferralTherapist(ReferralTherapist ReferralThep)
{
    _unitOfWork.ReferralTherapistRepository.Insert(ReferralThep);
    //_unitOfWork.Save(); THIS IS HOW IT WAS DONE AT FIRST
    return true;
}

public bool ExecuteSave()
{
    _unitOfWork.Save();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Add the code for the `adding each selected therapist` and the code for 'executing a Save command' and the calling code

Comment: I think you have the `SaveChanges` within the loop. Move that outside the loop. In other words add all the items to the context within the loop, then leave the loop and call `SaveChanges`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I formerly did it this way, and now I am not.  This works fine in the IDE, not on a live web server.

Comment: I ran this on my local IIS (Win 8.1 pro) outside the IDE and it worked as expected. Still does not work correctly on a live web server (meaning a Server OS)